# Flutter - Error at compiled application when adding toList() at spread

Tags: flutter

I got error type **'String' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast** when compiling my application like this after adding a List and toList() in the code :
[image]

Here is the **main.dart** that contains the List and toList() code, my application can run well when those code is taken out, I wonder what make it wrong.
I didn't find any error line in VS Code, but the error appears at compiler cmd and application :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './question.dart';
import './answer.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApps());
}

class MyApps extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return MyAppsState();
  }
}

class MyAppsState extends State<MyApps> {
  int indexQuestion = 0;

  void answerQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      indexQuestion += 1;
    });
    if (indexQuestion > 1) {
      indexQuestion = 1;
    }
    print('add index by 1');
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var questions = [
      {
        'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite animal?',
        'answers': ['cat', 'dog', 'elephant', 'fish'],
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite color?',
        'answers': ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'black'],
      },
    ];

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('My First App Yo!'),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Question(
                questions[indexQuestion]['questionText'],
              ),
              **//==============PROBLEM HERE===================================**
              ...(questions[indexQuestion]['questionText'] as List<String>)
                  .map((answer) {
                return Answer(answerQuestion, answer);
              }).toList(),
              **//===============================================================**
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: resetIndex,
                child: Text('Reset'),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the **answer.dart** :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function selectHandler;
  final String answerText;

  Answer(this.selectHandler, this.answerText);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, right: 50),
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Answer1'),
          color: Colors.blue,
          onPressed: () => selectHandler(),
        ),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

Here is the **question.dart** :

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Question extends StatelessWidget {
  final String questionText;

  Question(this.questionText);

  // Question({String questionTextoption}) {
  //   questionText = questionTextoption;
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(
        'aaa $questionText',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        maxLines: 2,
      ),
      width: double.infinity,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    );
  }
}
```

I just followed the flutter tutorial and got stuck here, any help would really help me now.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`questions[indexQuestion]['questionText']` is a String, you can't cast it to a `List<String>`.
`questions[indexQuestion]['answers']` would work tho.
And when you get this to work you will probably have layout errors due to nesting a `Column` inside a `Column`(Answer class) without `Expanded`.

Comment: Yes you are right! It works, thank you for the insight! Very helpful